# Running Selenium 2.32 fails on firefox 9.0 with Java

Tags: java, selenium

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal
>
> dialog present Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18',
>   time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22' System info: os.name: 'Windows 7',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_15' Session
>   ID: 349b227a-82f8-4068-905c-70f4dcd271ed Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{platform=XP,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true,
>   nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true, version=9.0.1}]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createUnhandledAlertException(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:216)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
>     at gamil.main(gamil.java:16)

Comment: What am I supposed to do with this information? Where's your code?

Answer (score 1):

well, that did not help too much. But you can try:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert;
alert.accept();
```

(hopefully the code is ok, putting it together from my head)

Basically, you can read from the stacktrace, that there is alert on your site. So you have to accept it or dismiss it.

If this does not help, more details is needed. Read http://whathaveyoutried.com and try to understand what it says

Answer (score 0):

There is an alert thats why `UnhandledAlertException` exception occurs:

```
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert;
  alert.accept();  //code to oK alert

//alert.dismiss();  //code to Cancel alert
```